# Select dynamic inner element, not static container

Tags: jquery

```js
$('#vehicle_area').on('click', '.vehicle_select' ,function(e){
      $(e.target).toggleClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
  });
```

```css
.selected{
background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='vehicle_area'>

  <div class='vehicle_select' id='vehicle_select_1'>
    <h3>Vehicle 1</h3>
    <p>this is a test</p>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class='vehicle_select' id='vehicle_select_2'>
    <h3>Vehicle 1</h3>
    <p>this is a test</p>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class='vehicle_select' id='vehicle_select_3'>
    <h3>Vehicle 1</h3>
    <p>this is a test</p>
    <hr>
  </div>

</div>
```

I'm trying to add a class to an element that has been generated dynamically within a static div. I've bound the jquery event to the static div's id and used .on() so that it will trigger any time an element inside with the class ".vehicle_select" is clicked, even if the element was created after page load.

This means however that the $(this) selector is refers to the static div, not to the element that was clicked.

I've tried using the code below however as expected this adds the class to the static element #vehicle_area, not to the element that was clicked.

How can I select the dynamic element that was clicked, not the static element to which the event is bound?

There are multiple elements with the class ".vehicle_select" within the div, so I'd like only to select the one which was clicked to trigger the event.

update: please see snippet. using event.target works better, however it selects any element within the container that was clicked, not just the one with the class .vehicle_select. so it's now selecting headers and paragraphs individually for example.

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure. I tried the event.target method, which didn't work as intended then switched back to "this" as per your answer, cleared my cache and it worked exactly as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this)` works. `e.target` is not working because that could be anything. You would need to click outside any children

```js
$('#vehicle_area').on('click', '.vehicle_select' ,function(e){
    console.log(e.target.tagName); // can be anything
    $(this).toggleClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});

$('#vehicle_area').html(`<div class='vehicle_select' id='vehicle_select_1'>
    <h3>Vehicle 1</h3>
    <p>this is a test</p>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class='vehicle_select' id='vehicle_select_2'>
    <h3>Vehicle 1</h3>
    <p>this is a test</p>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class='vehicle_select' id='vehicle_select_3'>
    <h3>Vehicle 1</h3>
    <p>this is a test</p>
    <hr>
  </div>
`)
```

```css
.selected { background-color:red }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='vehicle_area'>


</div>
```